# Passive voice with functional verbs

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Basically, which is correct and why?

- fire is attempted to start
- fire is attempted to be started

Comment: Both are ugly and shouldn't be used. Try "An attempt was made to start the fire" instead.

Comment: Good point, @Robusto, for the sake argument, what if I really had to?

Comment: Then I pity you.

Comment: Funny idea to express "They tried to make fire" in passive voice. Looks like silly  school book task. Maybe this remark gets me a minus point, but I could not refrain.

Comment: Actually it's not, @rogermue, it occurred at work, but I replaced immaterial subject and "action" verb with fire and start for brevity.

Comment: (a) Passive may be applied to transitive clauses only. (b) There are two verbs in this sentence, which means there are two clauses. (c) _Attempt_ requires a human subject, and _start_ is intransitive. (d) There are no human NPs in the sentences, so it is not clear what the corresponding active sentence might be -- maybe _`P` attempts to start a fire_, where `P` is some person. (e) The whole clause _to start a fire_ is the direct object of _attempt_, so that would be the new subject if _attempt_ were passivized  -- _To start a fire was attempted (by `P`)_, but that's not a really great sentence